# Java Spring Boot - CommandLineRunner for Async db operations thats runs in background

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, command-line, sleep

In my Spring Boot Application i'm trying to do some tasks in the background.

Getting data from one db, and store it in another, every 30min ish.

Would it be correct to make a CommandLineRunner class that takes care of this with @Async ?

```
@Component
public class UpdateDB implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
private WagerBoardMarksRepo loadRepo;

@Autowired
private StoreDbEntRepo storeRepo;

@Async
private static void update() {
    while (true) {

       // get data from loadRepo.
       // save data to storeRepo

        try {
            Thread.sleep("sleep for 30min"); // 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    update();
}
```

}

Comment: This wouldn't work because it firstly an internal method call (doesn't work due to proxies for AOP). Secondly you cannot apply `@Async` to `static` methods. So it will simply not work. `@Scheduled` is invented for that, don't try to create your own again. If you have large amounts of data you might want to consider combining this with Spring Batch.

Answer (score 2):

Scheduler is made for such operation, see the code below

```
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0,30 * * * * ?")
    public void update() {
        // get data from loadRepo.
        // save data to storeRepo
    }
}
```

And dont forget to use `@EnableScheduling` in your Startup class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```

See the [Scheduling Tasks](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) docs of spring for more details.